# Problems in MCS Lock Implementation - JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have written the following code (taken from the book "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming"):

```
package Chapter7;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class MCSLock implements Lock {

    AtomicReference<QNode> tail;
    ThreadLocal<QNode> myNode;

    public MCSLock() {
        tail = new AtomicReference<>(null);
        myNode = new ThreadLocal<QNode>() {
            @Override
            protected QNode initialValue() {
                return new QNode();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public void lock() {
        QNode qnode = myNode.get();
        QNode pred = tail.getAndSet(qnode);
        if (pred != null) {
            qnode.locked = true;
            pred.next = qnode;
            while (qnode.locked);   // line A
        }
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public void unlock() {
        QNode qnode = myNode.get();
        if (qnode.next == null) {
            if (tail.compareAndSet(qnode, null)) {
                return;
            }
            while (qnode.next == null);    // line B
        }
        qnode.next.locked = false;
        qnode.next = null;
    }

    class QNode {
        boolean locked = false;
        QNode next = null;
    }
}
```

This seems to work if I test it with a small number of threads and operations, but it goes in deadlock every time I try to use 8 threads and 1000 operations per thread protected by this Lock. I inserted some prints to debug the code and an other thread that collects data on the working threads. I found that:

- Sometimes the deadlock is on line A, sometimes on line B.
- In the first case, all the threads are looping on line A. The other thread that is collecting data, shows that the variables on which the threads are looping on are all true but one, so a thread should have the possibility to make progress!

  - In the second case, all threads but one are looping on line A, the other is looping on line B. The data-collecting thread shows that qnode.next is not null.
  - There are not starving threads since I checked that they are "active waiting" inserting simple counters (and they are increasing).

The test is done on a simple PriorityQueue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with this code is that it attempts to use `ThreadLocal` to achieve thread confinement. However, due to linking the `QNodes` in a linked list and manipulating instances through the `next` reference and the `tail` reference, it breaks that thread confinement, and in the absence of other synchronization mechanisms over the `QNode` fields, visibility of changes is not guaranteed between threads.

Continuing to loop in line A is a consequence of seeing a stale value, despite the `qnode.next.locked = false;` call in `unlock()`.

Similarly, continuing to loop in line B is a consequence of seeing a stale value, despite the `pred.next = qnode;` call in `lock()`.

In both cases fields of a `QNode` of another thread are mutated. In the former case `qnode.next`, and in the latter `pred` are `QNodes` of the other thread.

Comment: If I use Atomic variables in the QNode class, shloud I solve the problem? Something like AtomicBoolean and AtomicReference

Comment: Because the only "trick" I know is to use volatile variables, but using them in so many instances of the class QNode, does it lead to a degradation of the performances?

Comment: Using Atomic variables will work, as well as just marking them volatile in this case. Volatile is sufficient, since mutating the values never depends on the previous value.
As to performance, Atomic variables don't perform well under heavy contention, in which case volatiles will probably win out. When typical use is in low contention context, Atomic variables may win out. As always : make sure and measure.

Comment: Thank you, it was only an exercise but I will try to check if in my test volatile variables will outperform Atomic one.

Comment: The test with the volatile variables took about 40% less time than atomics. Running a longer test, the difference reduced to 15% but volatile var were still winning. (All test on my macbook with 8 threads using the MCS lock)

Answer (score 2):

If you run set `pred.next` in **thread_1**, then
    check `qnode.next` in **thread_2** with no synchronization, **thread_2**
    may never get the value you set in **thread_1** because of
    **[memory barrier](https://dzone.com/articles/memory-barriersfences)**.